# XPath multiple contains to return a single element

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following two XPath selectors working individually, but am unable to combine them to return the same element as a result:

```
//*[@customAttribute="banana"]//*[contains(@style,'width:100px')] 

//*[@customAttribute="banana"]//*[contains(label,'Name')]
```

The source around the element being targeted is as such:

```
<label 
id="randomID_1234" 
for="randomID_1234" 
class="class1 class2 class3" 
style="width:100px;margin-right:5px;" 
unselectable="on">
Name
</label>
```

Why not just return the element by label name? I must assert that the element is conforming to a certain style also. Is this possible to do with a one-liner?

Answer (score 1):

This one should do the trick:

```
//*[@customAttribute="banana"]//*[contains(label,'Name')][contains(@style,'width:100px')]
```

Comment: no dice with that, unfortunately. It is an ExtJS page, in case that is doing any of it's usual funkiness with the elements...

Answer (score 0):

This ended up doing the trick:

```
(//*[@customAttribute="banana"]//*[contains(label,'Name')])//*[contains(@style,'width:100px')]
```